# Where to ask less specific code questions?

Tags: support, scope

I'm having problems wrapping libmysql to the D programming language. I get weird crashes and no answers to solve the problem on the D forum.

Is there a Stack Exchange site for this kind of question?
It's not specific enough for Stack Overflow.
It's not for code review as it obviously has bugs.

Update: I asked it on Stack Overflow: [Problems converting a C header to D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204460/problems-convering-a-c-header-to-d)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect match for Stack Overflow. Why do you think it is not specific enough?

Comment: @Pekka: It's 1000 lines of wrapped .h files and I have no clue where the error(s) might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ask on stack overflow.  It's a programming question, and it's objective and answerable.  I'm not sure what makes you feel that it's not specific, but it seems very specific to me.

It sounds like you need to refine your debugging practices. Consider one error at a time.  Reproduce it.  Once you've got one error that you can reproduce consistently, search google, and post it to stack overflow. Since the codebase is large, place it as an archive on the Internet, or on pastebin, or in a repository and give the address/vcs information in the question.

Attack one observable and reproducable error at a time, and you'll find it both much easier to resolve, and much more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Surely we can try pointing out the error, and it looks fit for **Stack Overflow**. However **host it** somewhere like [pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) or any source code hosting site of your choice, so we may look at it and **fork it to improve** it. Posting whole code (1000 lines) on Stack Overflow itself will **distract** many possible answers.

Also if you can specify some block of code which is having problems then it will be easier to come up with solutions.

If you still don't get answers we have a feature of giving **bonus points** by the way of **Bounty**. Give away **500 points**, and you will have better chances of getting a perfect answer.

Comment: Hosting it somewhere else isn't an ideal situation since its still a 1000 line long wall of code. Its best if the OP can write a small test case.